# Can't center Bootstrap input-group in Webkit, but works fine in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a stubborn input group that won't center, and am completely stuck. The especially confusing bit is that it works great in Firefox, but not in Webkit browsers.

```css
.product {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.product 
  input[type="text"] {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90px;
  }

.product
  .prod-name {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }

.product
  .qty-choice {
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }

.product
    .input-group {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

.product .inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="product">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/240/240" width="240"
               height="240">
          <div class="prod-name">{{name}}</div>
          <div class="sku">{{sku}}</div>
          <div class="size">{{width}}" W x {{height}}" H</div>
          <div class="price">${{price}}</div>
          <div class="qty-choice inline-block">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">Variation 1</span>
              <input class="form-control qty"
                     type="text" placeholder="Enter Qty">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart">Add to
              Cart</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm still getting the hang of Bootstrap, but centering things has been extremely difficult. I assume my `.inline-block` class is not the correct way to go about this, otherwise it would work in both browsers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A little bit of searching around tells me there *might* be some sort of issue with `display: inline-block` in Webkit.

Answer (score 0):

Set an element to display: block and center via margin. Available as a mixin and class.

```
 <div class="center-block">...</div>
```

// Classes

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
```

}

Comment: It works fine. An input group is like a table, you can't give a width to the input and not the other, I'm amazed it worked in Webkit at all. http://jsbin.com/hoxubu/1/edit